# Make QGIS interface darker in Ubuntu

Tags: qgis-2, interface

Is there a way to make the interface of QGIS 2.0 darker in Ubuntu. I would prefer a darker theme closer to the Ubuntu Ambience style. Or is there a way to create personal themes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because QGIS is built using Qt you have the ability to use style sheets to change the style of the UI.  The Qt stylesheet are like CSS for `QWidget`s.  Pretty handy stuff.

You can make this

[image]

Look like this:

[image]

Using:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
QApplication.instance().setStyleSheet("QToolBar { background-color: rgb(85,85,85); border: 1px solid gray; }" )
```

There is more information on how to style Qt apps using a stylesheet at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html.

You should be able to style all of the interface like this.

Making a theme swapper would just be a matter of making a plugin that loads different stylesheets.